# Find Powerset of powerset of the empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The powerset of the empty set is {$\emptyset$}. Attempt:

The power set of the powerset of the empty set is { { {$\emptyset$} } }?

Next I want to find the powerset of the power set of the powerset of the empty set P(P(P($\emptyset$))).

Comment: Not quite. There are two subsets of $\{\emptyset\}$. In fact, there are two subsets of $\{a\}$ for any $a$.

Comment: I know $2^N$ elements.

Comment: So what are the subsets of $\{a\}$?

Comment: {a} and $\emptyset$

Comment: And so the power set of $\{a\}$ is...

Comment: { ${a}$, $\emptyset$}

Comment: And so the power set of $\{\emptyset\}$ is $\{\{\emptyset\},\emptyset\}$. That is, the power set of the power set of the empty set is $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\emptyset))=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$.

Comment: Careful, every element of the power set has to be a set :P

Comment: $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\emptyset)))$ must then have $2^2=4$ elements.

Comment: Is powerset actually an important concept in analysis, algebra, geometry?

Comment: (A quick LaTeX tip, by the way: To write square brackets, write `\{` and `\}`. Compare `${a}$` $\to$ ${a}$, and `$\{a\}$` $\to$ $\{a\}$.)

Comment: @brittany On occasion.

Comment: I meant _curly_ brackets (five years ago), not _square_, of course

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a visualization of $\emptyset$ (called $V_0$ here), $\mathcal P(\emptyset)$ (called $V_1$ here), $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\emptyset))$ (called $V_2$ here), etc. An empty box represents the empty set. A box containing only an empty box represents the set containing only the empty set, and so forth.

[image]

Thus:

- $V_0=\{\}$
- $V_1=\{\{\}\}$
- $V_2=\{\{\},\{\{\}\}\}$ (this is the powerset of the powerset)
- $V_3=\{\{\},\{\{\}\},\{\{\{\}\}\},\{\{\},\{\{\}\}\}$
- etc.

$V_5$, not pictured, has $2^{2^{\large 2^{2}}}=65,\!536$ elements.

EDIT:

To be explicit, the definition is $V_0=\emptyset$ and $V_{n+1}=\mathcal P(V_n)$. There are two properties of these you should know:

- *Every* "hereditarily finite set" (that is, a set you could write with a finite number of curly braces) is contained in one of those $V$  sets.
- $V_n\subset V_{n+1}$ for all $n$. That is, each is a subset of the next one.

Can you see why these are true?

Comment: The picture doesn't add much new insight other than 1) they get big _really_ quickly and 2) they're a bit of a mess

Comment: There should be carpets with that....

Comment: Image credit Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

If it makes things easier you can use labels.  The "whooo, trippy, power set of a  power set of an empty set" nature shouldn't distract us from what is actually straightforward.

$A = \emptyset = \{\}$ is a set with zero elements.

$B= P(A) = \{A\} = \{\emptyset\} = \{\{\}\}$ is a set with $2^0 = 1$ element. (Note: for any set $K$, two subsets that will always exist are the two non-proper subsets of $K$ and $\emptyset$.  In this case $A$ = \emptyset$)

$B= P(A) = \{\emptyset\}$ is, in essence, nothing more or less than a set with one element.  That the one element just happens to be the emptyset ("whooo, freaky") doesn't make any difference at all.

$C=P(B) = \{B, \emptyset\}= \{\{A\}, \emptyset\}= \{\{\emptyset\}, \emptyset\}$

Or $C=P(B) = P(P(\emptyset) = \{\{\emptyset\}, \emptyset\}$.  This is a set with $2^1 =2$.  For each of the one element, $A=\emptyset$, in $B = P(\emptyset)$ the two subsets are i) The set that contains $A = \emptyset$, that is, the set $\{A\} = \{\emptyset\}$ and ii) the set that does not contain $A = \emptyset$, that is, ... the emptyset.